# Building a new API for a constant changing Database

Tags: mysql, database, reactjs, api-design

I'm planning on rebuilding a web application, and one of the point's is rebuilding It's API, since the MySql database is constatly changing It takes a lot of work to make small change's, I'm trying to think of a way to make things easier when it comes to making changes in the database.And then I'll rebuild the front-end with a framework like React or Vue.js.

What are your thought's?

Comment: Why is the database "constantly changing?"

Comment: The database is always changing because it's a database from a crm of a company and there's always new improvements to be made

Comment: You may need to provide a more concrete example of the kinds of changes you are referring to and why they are problematic. A well-designed database may be *extended* to add new functionality, but "constantly changing" -- the way I interpret it, which may admittedly be wrong -- seems to imply it isn't well-designed and is inherently unstable. To some extent, stored procedures can be used to define an abstraction interface to the tables so that your code doesn't access tables directly, but it's hard to say whether this would be a helpful strategy.  Examples of what you are dealing with may help.

Comment: Every time i insert a new field in a table like adding a boolean field to determine if a user in the application is a normal  or a other kind of user since we give a special acess to certain client of our company.And I have to change the table i have to procede to change a lot of code to and all the function that use that table of the database .

Comment: It sounds like you need a better model.  Adding boolean columns for access control would be a nightmare, and easy to get wrong.  For a simple scenario, think of the "user" table (existing) and a "permission" table (new, listing individual permissions and giving each of them an ID) and a many-to-many "user_has_permission" table (new), with just two columns, user_id and permission_id.  If the user has a certain permission, there would be a row in the table indicating so.

Comment: What I have right now it's a merge of both, i have a permission table and as well a permission group table. But since both types of user's use the same page it's sometimes complicated, my idea in redoing almost everything in the app is spliting things the special users use a diferent page of the normal users because any change in the page for the normal users it causes a lot of erros in the special user page

Comment: That's a strategy that only you can determine whether it is sensible. I don't think a generic/universal answer is possible. A solid design should not make it easy to break things unrelated to what you're changing, but if the same functionality is exposed to both classes of users, you don't want those to be duplicated.

Comment: So should i rebuild the databse as well?